# Exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest when running Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, apache-commons

I am working on a simple Upload JSP and Servlet tutorial outlined here :

[Upload Tutorial](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/667-how-write-servlet-uploads-file-server.html)

I have the system coded and my webpage finished but I am getting errors when running the application. When I click on the upload button, such as :

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadServlet] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    at com.dell.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The tomcat page I'm being directed too looks as follows :

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbNCn.jpg)

Anybody know what I've done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot/missed to add  the  [apache common fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) `jar`

```
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.
                     isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
```

Check your `lib/maven jar` structure.

Comment: Hi, I added it to the buildpath of the project and the Server launch configuration classpath of the server and I still get an error

Comment: @MattMcGrath You checked that is it in `lib` folder ?

Comment: It's not in the lib but in the classpath, should I add it to the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: @MattMcGrath Yes,Please :)

Comment: I still get the same error unfortunately...
Could it be my web.xml?

Comment: No,usually ClassNotFound comes ,when we forgot to add required jar files,And I did'nt see any clue related to web.xml also :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34909/discussion-between-suresh-atta-and-matt-mcgrath)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception - different circumstances, but in my case, servlet-api.jar was clearly where it should be `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/`, however I installed jars that were compiled against a different servlet-api.jar and produced this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
```

The quick fix was to use the servlet-api.jar the servlets were originally compiled with, though in production I'd recommend recompiling your servlet instead of replacing tomcat's core jars.